# How to enable root login on fedora?

Tags: ssh, fedora, ftp

I've followed [**this guide**](https://github.com/forem/selfhost) in order to install an instance of forem on digital ocean.
Well, I've succeeded :) But the guide is using a key for login and I'm not able from the core user to access all the files of the script on the server I need the root login in order to access them through FTP.

I've already tried editing the sshd_config file and setting **PermitRootlogin to yes** and **Strict mode to no**, but I get this error:

`Permission denied (publickey,password).`

Any idea how to fix this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try in `vsftpd.conf` to add the following line: `userlist_deny=YES`; and comment out `root` from the files (if exist) `/etc/ftpusers` and `/etc/vsftpd/ftpusers` and `/etc/vsftpd/user_list` with a hash (`#`) at the start of the line. ([link](https://serverfault.com/questions/34678/how-to-configure-vsftpd-to-allow-root-logins))